Why encode RISCV PseudoInstruction LI to four instructions instead of two?
Dear RISCV enthusiasts,
My question is about encoding
li t1, 0xFF00F007

When using https://riscvasm.lucasteske.dev/# the code above encodes to
   0:   000ff337            lui t1,0xff
   4:   00f3031b            addiw   t1,t1,15
   8:   00c31313            slli    t1,t1,0xc
   c:   00730313            addi    t1,t1,7 # ff007 <_sstack+0xee607>

In my naive attempt to encode the instructions, I came up with
[0] lui sp, 0xFF00F         # --pseudo--> I_LI -> FF00F137
[4] addiw t1, sp, 0x7       # --pseudo--> I_LI -> 0071031B

I must be missing something.
My questions are:
1. is my own attempt correct?
2. If it is correct, why would https://riscvasm.lucasteske.dev/#
output 4 instructions instead of 2 ? It seems that 4 instructions are less performant than 2.
Thanks for your input.
I tried my own code in the RISCV interpreter https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3410/2019sp/riscv/interpreter/
and it seems that the correct immediate ends up in the register.
So I am not seeing what I did wrong.

You're using a 64-bit machine because the code sequences are using addiw.
The question is whether 0xFF00F007 should be considered signed or not.
Apparently, that online assembler treats such constant as unsigned.  Let's note that RARS considers that same construct as a signed constant, so it does your code sequence.
Their sequence loads 0x00000000FF00F007 into t1, while your sequence loads 0xFFFFFFFFFF00F007.
The reason being that on 64-bit machines, lui sign extends.
If you tried it on the Cornell simulator, you would have had to change addiw to addi, because that is a 32-bit machine simulator, and 32-bit RISC V machines don't have addiw.

The normal convention for assembly language is that constants are the mathematical values we want, not the encoding.  It would be insane if 1<<30, 1<<31, 1<<32, etc. didn't all assemble to single-bit constants, if 1<<31 was actually -1<<31 because the assembler saw it was a "32-bit" constant and sign-extended it to 64.  If RARS assembles li t1, 0xFF00F007 to li t1, 0xFFFFFFFFFF00F007, that sounds like a RARS bug unless there's a different pseudo-instruction for 64-bit values, and li is only supposed to materialize the low 32 bits you asked for.

Oh, but I was forgetting that the normal convention on MIPS64 and RISC-V is for 32-bit values to be sign-extended to 64-bit.  x86-64 and AArch64 zero-extend when you write a 32-bit register.  So I guess I can see why you might sign-extend. But how to you get RARS to li values that fit in a u32 but not i32?  Do you write li t1, 0x00000000FF00F007?

@PeterCordes, yes, that 64-bit hex value works for RARS, and, it generates a lovely 8 instruction sequence to load that u32.

@PeterCordes, sorry if I wasn't clear.  RARS accepts li t1, 0x00000000FF00F007 and produces an 8 instruction sequence to achieve that — 0x00000000FF00F007 in the target register.  So, the other assembler the querant mentions makes a shorter sequence for this, and, I might agree that it is problematic/a bug that the RARS interpretation of 32 bit hex value is signed.

Yeah, just noticed you said "64-bit hex value", which implies you meant the one with 16 hex digits.  8 instructions... at least nobody's using RARS to build production binaries.  Is it possible to build it in 3 instructions?  Like lui / shift / add?  But if the add needs to set bit #11, you can't do that without having it also sign-extend.  So 0x00...FF000007 can be constructed in 3 insns, lui t1, 0xff000>>1 / addw t1,t1,t1 / addi t1, t1, 7.  But maybe not the OP's constant where the bottom bit of the upper 20 bits is set.

@PeterCordes, I can't come up with a shorter code sequence than 4 instructions off the top of my head.  We can use addi, it will sign extend, but just add 1 to the lui to mitigate that.  However, both some mid bits and the low bit (LSB) of the desired value are set so needs a addi shift, addi.  I don't see how to get there with a single addi (after the shift we don't have enough immediate bits to do the upper bits job (0xF000 part), and before the shift we cannot get to the desired LSB (0x7).  Could use the sign extending version, then cancel that but that adds 2 instruction (2+2).

Thank you all for your input and @ErikEidt for your answer. I have not even considered 64 bit vs 32 bits and the sign extension of immediates. I will add these bits of information to the things I have learned so far. Thank you very much.
